# Difference among explicit indexing and implicit indexing?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I am learning Database and currently I am using mysql. While practicing it I got a doubt regarding the indexing and wanted to know what exactly is the difference between implicit and explicit indexing? Which is better? Considering that i will be using more of the update, insert and delete commands over the database, which is better suited that time and why?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The term "implicit index" is sometimes used to refer to indexes that are created by operations other than `create index`.  This occurs in two particular cases:

- Primary key definitions in tables
- Unique constraints

And, I am not sure if the use of the `key`/`index` keyword in `create table` is considered implicit or explicit.

There is no difference between the these indexes per se.  There is a difference between primary key and non-primary key indexes -- primary key indexes *may* result in the table being physically ordered by the index (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)).

Neither is better.  "Implicit" indexes have the advantage that they are part of the table definition.  "Explicit" indexes have the advantage that they are created explicitly.  Other than the definition, the use of the index in queries should be the same.